# Three Key combination for AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I found out how to remap *Caps Lock* and *S* to something else: `CapsLock &:: ...`

But how can I have a combination with three keys like *CTRL*, *ALT* and *S*?

Answer (score 1):

Per the official [AutoHotKey Mouse, Joystick and Keyboard Shortcuts](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) documentation:

```
^!s::Send foo
```

Note, however, this only works with multiple modifier keys (*Ctrl*, *Shift*, *Alt*). Regarding "other" three key combinations, the documentation currently states:

> Combinations of three or more keys are not supported. Combinations which your keyboard hardware supports can usually be detected by using #If and GetKeyState, but the results may be inconsistent.

It goes on to give this example of how this last part might be accomplished:

```
; Press AppsKey and Alt in any order, then slash (/).
#if GetKeyState("AppsKey", "P")
Alt & /::MsgBox Hotkey activated.

; If the keys are swapped, Alt must be pressed first (use one at a time):
#if GetKeyState("Alt", "P")
AppsKey & /::MsgBox Hotkey activated.

; [ & ] & \::
#if GetKeyState("[") && GetKeyState("]")
\::MsgBox
```